# High quality images in imageview?

Tags: android, url, imageview

i'm loading images from url into imageview using LazyAdapter.
http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/parrot_high_resolution-normal.jpg into the imageview and it looks horrible! Does anyone know how to fix it?
Here's my codes :

```
     final JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        hm.put("phoneimage", json.getString("imageurl"));
                        resultList.add(hm);
                    }
                    arrowfront.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            position++;
                            HashMap<String, String> frontHm = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            imageLoader.DisplayImage(frontHm.get("phoneimage"),themainimage);
```

As for the xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivdisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: do you decode the bitmap before showing it ?

Comment: i'm using lazyadapter.

Comment: yes, i think it have a resizing or decoding code, that's why the image qulity is horrible, look into your code if there is any decoding to the bitmap

Comment: Sir, these are the files of LazyList 
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/tree/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist

Comment: ok check my answer i hope it will be helpful, and dont forget to say Shokran ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented LazyAdapter before, and it encode the bitmap before proccesing it to the UI, because loading the high quality image to the UI will lead to high memory usage that will force the app to close, i have looked into the example code you provided and as you can see in ImageLoader class there's an encoding to the bitmap at line 89. 
goto class ImageLoader and search for `final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;` and change `70` to `200` and see if it can help .

Comment: Shokran sir for your help! i hope you rate my question up so it can help other people :) thanks again :)

Comment: did it work ? is the image quality now looks better? try to clean the catch to see the new one.

Comment: sir is it okay to use 300?

Comment: @KingOmar clean catch so you can see the new images.

Comment: @KingOmar be careful not to set a hight number becuase it will lead to leak of memory use 200 as max. and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Android Query rom here
http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query.0.25.10.jar

and implement it on you imageView

```
    AQuery aq = new AQuery(ImageView); // your imageview object 
    aq.id(R.id.imageview).image("urlofImage");
```

it will automatically set image to your imagevew

Comment: He is complaning about the image quality.